# How to properly Abort from within a ParallelMap?

Tags: parallelization, map

If a condition is met within a sub-kernel in the function being mapped, how does one cancel the whole `ParallelMap` operation?

```
ParallelMap[
 Check[Pause[1]; 
   If[# > 10, Print[$KernelID, " failed on ", #]; $Failed, 
    Print[$KernelID, " suceeded on ", #]], AbortKernels[]] &, 
 Range[20]]
```

This seems like something commonplace, but I can't remember how or find it anywhere in the docs!

Comment: Looks like you want [`ParallelTry`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html)

Comment: It’s sort of the opposite - ParallelTry returns the first successful result, I want to stop on the first failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting the code from [`ParallelTry`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html) to do what you need, we get

```
ComputeUntilFailure[f_, _[args___]] := Module[
  {ids, id, r, res = <||>},
  DistributeDefinitions[{f, args}];
  ids = List @@ ParallelSubmit /@ (# -> f@# &) /@ Hold[args];
  While[Length@ids > 0,
   {r, id, ids} = WaitNext[ids];
   If[FailureQ@Last@r,
    AbortKernels[];
    Clear@ids;
    Break[],
    AppendTo[res, r]
    ]
   ];
  res
  ]
```

Basically, this uses [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) to launch the computations on parallel kernels. The results are then processed one by one on the main kernel using [`WaitNext`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitNext.html), until one of them is a failure, at which point we abort the remaining computations.

Applying this to the example given in the question:

```
ComputeUntilFailure[
  (
    Pause@1; 
    If[# > 10,
      Print[$KernelID, " failed on ", #];
      $Failed,
      Print[$KernelID, " succeeded on ", #]
    ]
  ) &,
  Range[20]
]
(* 6 succeeded on 1 *)
(* 5 succeeded on 2 *)
(* 4 succeeded on 3 *)
(* 3 succeeded on 4 *)
(* 2 succeeded on 5 *)
(* 1 succeeded on 6 *)
(* 6 succeeded on 7 *)
(* 5 succeeded on 8 *)
(* 4 succeeded on 9 *)
(* 3 succeeded on 10 *)
(* 2 failed on 11 *)
(* 1 failed on 12 *)
(* <|1 -> Null, 2 -> Null, 3 -> Null, 4 -> Null, 5 -> Null, 
 6 -> Null, 7 -> Null, 8 -> Null, 9 -> Null, 10 -> Null|> *)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example usage of this?

Comment: I'm wondering why does it not abort after it fails on 11?

Comment: @M.R. The issue is that all the tasks finish almost exactly simultaneously. So when the main thread got the first failed result from Kernel 2, Kernel 1 also produces a failed result (almost) the same instant, before the main kernel has any chance to abort the computation. If you replace the `Pause[1]` statement with `Pause@RandomReal[]` (to force the different kernels to be less synchronous), it will only generate a single failed result in most cases.

Comment: Interesting, I’d consider that a bug in the parallel functions

Comment: @M.R. why? I would say that that's just the nature of concurrent programs (If you want to avoid that things finish simultaneously, you can simply remove the parellization ;-) ) Also, note that the returned list contains neither of the two failed instances, as expected

Comment: Because it seems like a race condition that could be handled right?

Comment: @M.R. how would you handle it? The problem is that the tasks just happen to finish at the same time which can't really be avoided. And until the first failure has been encountered, we have no choice but to start new tasks if we want it to be parallelized. So every time the computation will be aborted, some amount of other tasks will be currently running. In this example is just happens to be visible (due to the print statement). Or am I completely missing your point?

Comment: Right, not sure how to handle it...

Comment: Have to replace AppendTo... why no DistributeDefinitions?

Comment: @M.R. Regarding `DistributeDefinitions`: Good catch, I've updated the answer. Regarding `AppendTo`: What do you mean?